# SQL Server - Copy data from restored version to live database table

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. 
I have a database called LabDB.
I have a issue where some data was deleted in the database. 
What I like to do is to restore the backed up version of the database in Object Explorer and then 
copy the missing data from the backed up version to the live database.

Can somebody please guide me on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Note: While I believe these steps to be accurate I take no responsibility for any lost data. Use at your own risk.

1. Right click on the databases folder in object explorer (it should be listed beneath your server name)
2. Choose device and click on the ellipsis button. Find the backup file you wish to restore
3. Change the destination database to another database name (you don't want to overwrite your existing database)
4. Choose files on the LHS. Make sure to change the Restore As field so that you do not overwrite your existing mdf or ldf files
5. Write queries to insert into  select * from

Comment: Hi JP. For #4 where do I do this at? Choose files on the LHS, etc.

Comment: You should see a navigation section on the left hand side of the restore database dialog with 3 options (General/Files/Options). It is the second one. Tell me if you do not.

Comment: As stated above restore the database using a different name and relocate the files for the database. If you are not comfortable in writing the queries you can use SQL Data compare from RedGate or similar software to aid you

Answer (score 1):

You have basically already solved your problem, you can restore your back up to another DB, then compare the table you are looking for between the LabDB and the BackUp DB now restored, and see which data is missing, and then move it to that. All you have to do is make sure your queries contain the database name. Something along the lines of

```
 Select * from RestoredDB.dbo.TableA r where not exists (select * from LabDB.dbo.TableA p where r.id = p.id)
```

This should give you all the data that is in the restored database that is not in the production database. Granted you will have to switch your table name and columns to match yours.